# Build error in Netbeans while using mingw

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I have been trying to connect MinGW to Netbeans and I have downloaded and installed MinGW correctly, pointed to it in NEtbeans and also edited my PATH Environment variables. However, I am getting this build error while building a sample C++ project to test the compiler.

```
"/c/Users/Mahe/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1/"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
/bin/sh: /c/Users/Mahe/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1/C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe: No such file or directory
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 127


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 375ms)
```

It seems like the path is wrong to the compiler. Instead of taking the absolute path, Netbeans is taking the path relative to the project folder. What is wrong and how can I correct this?

Comment: If you setup a simple test project (default C++ Application) with a single main file, is this working? If you check the compiler paths in netbeans, are they ok?

Comment: Yup. They are okay, apparently, there is some bug with netbeans which breaks the mingw.

Comment: Btw., what version of Netbeans are you using?

Comment: 7.1.1 Havent upgraded in a while.

Comment: Okay, found a solution here https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228730. The make path could be just set to make.exe instead of the whole directory.